# Web service request gets stuck while switching between application in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession, app-transport-security, cfnetwork

We are trying to make a call to web service (nonsecure i.e. HTTP) in `Xamarin.iOS`. As it is an `http` URL we have added `NSAppTransportSecurity` to bypass the secure access.

Currently, we are using `HttpClient` with `NSUrlSessionHandler` so that `ATS config` specified in `info.plist` gets applied.

```
client = new HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler());
```

**Problem #1**

Now, the issue is whenever we are firing the web service request and after that, if we switch to a different app and come back to our app, the request gets stuck and does not return anything. if we stay on our app, it returns the response successfully.

**Problem #2**

In order to resolve `Problem#1` issue of switching app, we tried `client = new HttpClient(new CFNetworkHandler());` i.e. using `CFNetworkHandler` and that resolves our issue but this eventually creates another issue of accessing `http` URL. As we have used `CFNetworkHandler` , configurations related to `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `info.plist` gets ignored. As [Apple Developer Document says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections)

> ATS doesn’t apply to calls your app makes to lower-level networking
> interfaces like the Network framework or CFNetwork.

Error that we get while calling webservice with `CFNetwork` is as follows and it looks like `info.plist` config is getting ignored

```
StatusCode: 505, ReasonPhrase: 'HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.CFContentStream, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 06:15:19 GMT
  Connection: close
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
  Content-Length: 350
}
```

However, on the other end,[Microsoft Xamarin Says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#config)

```
App Transport Security does not apply to Xamarin apps using Managed HTTPClient implementations. It applies to connections using CFNetwork HTTPClient implementations or NSURLSession HTTPClient implementations only.
```

So, if we use `NSUrlSessionHandler` the request got stuck while switching app and if we use `CFNetworkHandler` then ATS won't allow to access the services.

ATS Configurations are as follows

1. set `NSAppTransportSecurity` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`
2. set `NSExceptionDomains` with following parameters

   a. `naaxdev.cloudapp.net`

   b. `NSIncludesSubdomains` set to `YES`

   c. `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` set to `YES`

   d. `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` set to `NO`

Comment: If you are getting a 505, that is a response from the server because your connection is being made with HTTP/1.1.  That is not and ATS error.  ATS would actually prevent the network request from being made at that old of a version.  What you need to figure out is: why is the CFNetwork request is trying to use HTTP/1.1? Or: Why does the server not support TLS 1.1?